# multi-line grep not making list

Tags: grep

I have a grep line that someone else provided for me that I don't know how to change.

The original line was this:

```
grep id=\"desc\"* $ADDON_SETTINGS | awk -v ORS=, '{gsub(/"/, "");print $2}' | tr -s 'value=' ' ' | sed 's/ //g' | echo "[$(cat)]"
```

And it pulled from a file that contained the following (this is a sample segment):

```
<settings>
  <setting id="cfirst" value="false" />
  <setting id="cicons" value="false" />
  <setting id="days" value="3" />
  <setting id="delay" value="0.000000" />
  <setting id="desc01" value="10" />
  <setting id="desc02" value="18" />
  <setting id="desc03" value="6" />
  <setting id="desc04" value="13" />
  <setting id="desc05" value="6" />
...
```

It pulled out the value for lines with "desc" in the id and resulted in a list:

```
10,18,6,13,6...
```

Now the program that generates the data file has changed the data to look like this:

```
<settings version="2">
  <setting id="allc" default="true">false</setting>
  <setting id="cfirst" default="true">false</setting>
  <setting id="cicons" default="true">false</setting>
  <setting id="days">3</setting>
  <setting id="delay" default="true">0</setting>
  <setting id="desc01">10</setting>
  <setting id="desc02">18</setting>
  <setting id="desc03">6</setting>
  <setting id="desc04">13</setting>
...
```

I figured this might be easier as I just need to pull the value between > and < but if I use this:

```
grep id=\"desc\"* $ADDON_SETTINGS | awk -v ORS=, '{">|<";print $3}' | echo "[$(cat)]"
```

But it's not working right. Not sure what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ awk -F'[<>]' '/"desc/{printf "%s%s",c,$3; c=","} END{print""}' file
10,18,6,13
```

How it works:

- `-F'[<>]'`

  This tells awk to use `<` or `>` as field separators.
- `/"desc/{printf "%s%s",c,$3; c=","}`

  For any line that containst `"desc`, this tells awk to print the variable `c` followed by the third field.  The third field is the number we want.  The variable `c` is initially the empty string but after the first print, we set it to a comma, `,`.  This causes the numbers we want to be printed, each separated by a comma.
- `END{print""}`

  After we have finished reading the file, this tells awk to print a newline character.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your solution doesn't work is `'{">|<";print $3}'`, which doesn't make sense. The expression `">|<"` doesn't do anything. You want a line like:

```
$ grep id=\"desc input.txt | awk -F"<|>" '{print $3}'
```

However, a single **awk** solution is:

```
awk 'match($0,/id=\"desc[0-9]+\">([0-9]+)/, a){printf "%s%s",sep,a[1];sep=","} END{print ""}' input.txt
10,18,6,13
```

or: with a file:

```
$ cat tst.awk
match($0,/id=\"desc[0-9]+\">([0-9]+)/, a){
   printf "%s%s",sep,a[1];sep=","
}
END{print ""}

$ awk -f tst.awk input.txt
10,18,6,13
```

Explanation:

- the match with regex `id=\"desc[0-9]+\">([0-9]+)` puts the number between parentheses in a[1].
- Print a[1] with the separator `sep`, which hasn't a value the first time around.
- END: you need to print a newline.

Answer (score 0):

Your content has html/xml format. 
The proper way would be to use html/xml parsers.

[**xmlstarlet**](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/xmlstarlet-ug.html) solution:

Sample `input.html` content:

```
<settings version="2">
  <setting id="allc" default="true">false</setting>
  <setting id="cfirst" default="true">false</setting>
  <setting id="cicons" default="true">false</setting>
  <setting id="days">3</setting>
  <setting id="delay" default="true">0</setting>
  <setting id="desc01">10</setting>
  <setting id="desc02">18</setting>
  <setting id="desc03">6</setting>
  <setting id="desc04">13</setting>
</settings>
```

---

The job:

```
res=($(xmlstarlet sel -t -v "//setting[contains(@id, 'desc')]" 1.html | tr '\n' ' '))
```

This will extract `<setting>` tag values with attribute `id` containing `"desc"` and make them items of the array `res`

Check the 2nd array item value:

```
echo ${res[1]}
18
```

Comment: This is probably the best way to go as the file is xml.  I figured out the regular settings using:  `xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/settings/setting[contains(@id, 'cicons')]" $ADDON_SETTINGS`  but I need to output the value of all the `"desc"` lines with a comma between.  So the output from the snippet above should read `10,18,6,13`

Comment: @edit4ever, just change `tr '\n' ' '` to `tr '\n' ','` and you'll get the desired sequence

Answer (score 0):

**grep** digits between `desc\d+">` and `<`

```
grep -oP 'desc\d+">\K\d+(?=<)' file | paste -sd ","
```

This will capture digits between `desc\d+">` and `<`.
Note:`desc\d+` would resolve to desc01, desc02 etc

`-o` is used to capture groups
`-P` tells it is a perl regex
`\K` is a lookbehind assertion which tells to start capturing data
`(?=)` is a lookahead assertion which here tells to stop capturing data once `<` is found